# Browser Not Picking Up Changes After Chrome Audit

Tags: html, caching, iis, browser, hosting

I had a Django webpage that worked. Then I started running Chrome audits and consequently added media and defer tags to several of my scripts, as well as several other changes. I then removed the tags, and now my page is still loading the scripts as if the tags are still there. It also will not pick up any other changes to the html (i.e. title change). I have tried different browsers. I have tried clearing my cache. I have tried incognito tabs. The request is a 200 request.

I am using Atom as my code editor and hosting on IIS. The webpage is an intranet site. I am working on the correct file.

**EDIT:** I tried adding a new page to the Django project. It shows up, and then it promptly does not respond to any further changes.

**EDIT 2:** I turned off caching in IIS, and this seemed to work for a while (so much so, that I wrote an answer to this question). However, I then ran a Chrome audit again, and the issue reemerged. No changes are recognized anymore.

**EDIT 3:** It appears to be selective in which changes are picked up and how quickly. I just changed the title and added a favicon at the same time. The favicon shows up in the browser, the title change does not. I then removed the favicon, and it remained in the browser.

Since the erratic behavior is happening cross-browser, I think it might have something to do with the server and how it is being hosted. As mentioned above, disabling caching on IIS did not permanently resolve the issue.

Why are my changes not being picked up?

Comment: How are you running the page? Through ATOM? or on localhost?  I would say rename the parent html file and see. make sure you are changing and testing same file.

Comment: it's running on IIS. i logged off, came home, and now it's back to the original. however, it won't pick up changes again (including changing the filename). i'm positive i'm working on the correct file - tried a couple other pages as well...same issue

Comment: If you add a totally new page/file, does it come up or do you get a 404?

Comment: @manassehkatz it shows up, and then promptly does not respond to changes

Comment: looks like more on server side issue. Do you have any other webserver? Run it with IDE enabled temp server or something...

Comment: it seems to just be a latency between the server and the client. it is still odd that it's picking and choosing. for instance, i just changed something in CSS and something in HTML. CSS shows up, HTML does not.